# What is the font in the Billund Airport Logo?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

I'm trying to figure out what font was used in this logo. This is the logo for the aiport in Billund, Denmark. I've searched many websites and couldn't find it.

[image]

Comment: Hi Brian, we have some [requirements](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2366) for font identification questions, please take a look and [edit] your question to include that information. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it's a custom font. Consists of regular and Bold. inspired by the classic monospaced Split-flap display boards at airports. It's not really monospaced since it was also made to look better and be more readable in print, on screens, and wayfinding. I made it back in 2001 as a Senior designer for Kontrapunkt Design in Copenhagen. The font won the Agfa-Monotype special prize, Trophée d’Or in 2002. I now run my own studio LOOP Associates. https://loopassociates.com
Hope this answer your question :)[image]

Comment: welcome to the community!

Answer (score 2):

Check out Handel Gothic medium. It's quite close.

Comment: Good catch and welcome. Unfortunately it's not it, check the other answers. Check the [tour] if you want to learn more about the site.

Answer (score 1):

Using the *WhatFont* [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/whatfont/jabopobgcpjmedljpbcaablpmlmfcogm?hl=en) (also confirming using dev tools) I was able to identify the name of the font - **Billund Airport**

Basically, a custom made font, which seems to be very similar to [PF Isotext Pro](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/parachute/pf-isotext-pro/regular/glyphs.html).

They likely found a font they liked and custom modified it.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really have something to do with PhotoShop I believe but nevertheless allow me to go through the steps I've used to find it out.

1. For Chrome add this extention [FOUNT](http://fount.artequalswork.com/) to your browser.

   1a. This is how it works:

   - Go to any site and click the Fount bookmarklet.
   - Click on any type you want to identify. Repeat.
   - To turn Fount off, just click the bookmarklet again.
2. Go to the website of the airport | https://www.bll.dk/
3. Follow the steps from 1a. The application tells me that they use Sans Serif (Size: 16PX / Weight: 400 / Style: Normal) & BillundAirport (Size: 16PX / Weight: 400 / Style: Normal)

So judging from this information I think it is safe to assume that the font type the airport is using is a custom font type called "BillundAirport".

Hope this helps!

Comment: in fact you don't need any plugin: just right-click on any title in the airport website and select "Inspect". You'll see the font name in the "Styles" section.

Comment: It is indeed called _Billund Airport_, and it was custom-designed for the airport by Kontrapunkt in Copenhagen in 2002 or 2003. It won the Trophée d’Or in 2003.